sqlite3, SQL. Почему оператор CASE не работает?
import sqlite3 as sq 

with sq.connect("test12.db") as con:
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users2") 

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users2 ( 
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
        name TEXT, 
        surname TEXT, 
        age INTEGER,  
        limit_ TEXT                   
        ) 
        """) 

cur.execute("INSERT INTO users2 (id,name,surname, age, limit_) VALUES (NULL, 'Иван','Самарин', 67,'')") 
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users2 (id,name,surname, age, limit_) VALUES (NULL, 'Алесандр','Синицин', 41,'')") 
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users2 (id,name,surname, age, limit_) VALUES (NULL, 'Григорий','Петров', 36,'')") 
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users2 (id,name,surname, age, limit_) VALUES (NULL, 'Федор','Васильев', 10,'')") 

cur.execute(""" 
SELECT name, surname, age, limit_ 
CASE  
WHEN age > 40 THEN 'age > 40' 
WHEN age < 40 THEN 'age < 40' 
END limit_ 
FROM users2 
""")

выдает sqlite3.OperationalError: near "CASE": syntax error

SELECT name, surname, age, limit_ --  Тут нет запятой после limit_
CASE  
WHEN age > 40 THEN 'age > 40' 
WHEN age < 40 THEN 'age < 40' 
END limit_  -- Тут совпадает название колонки с предыдущей
FROM users2 

